# Setting language to en-UK in Selenium Chrome for Behat tests

Tags: php, selenium, symfony, docker, behat

I am currently trying to run some behat tests using the `@javascript` tag. I am running a docker environment with Symfony 3.2 and I have attempted to change the language for chrome by setting an argument within the `behat.yml`:

```
  chrome:
     switches:
       - "--window-size=1200,800"
       - "--lang=en-UK"
```

The problem I am trying to fix is the fact that `<input type='date' />` is asking for an American format but I need the format to be UK in Selenium Chrome...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

There is no known fix for this anywhere after deep research. The fix was to change the date that I was sending across from `1970-01-31` to `12-31-1970`... if there is a better solution out there it will help with future projects/use of Selenium.

The reason this can be done, there is no gaurentee that the user will always have a UK based browser.

Other solutions are welcome :)

Comment: Same issue here.. And with UTC too while a field is supposed to have the "now datetime", I'm stuck with UTC+1.

Comment: @Delphine annoying but looks as if there is no workaround and we just have to put it into account for our tests :(